# Interpreting and diagnosing cause of server board "power good dropout error" -- no POST

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power

Motherboard: Intel S5520UR ([manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/s5520ur/sb/e44031012_s5520ur_s5520urt_tps_r1_9.pdf)). (Server chassis: SR2625URBRPR, but mostly irrelevant to this issue.)

I was being stupid earlier when trying to [solve a problem with the backplane](https://serverfault.com/questions/977787/non-hotpluggable-sata-iii-hard-drives-in-intel-sr2625urbrpr-backplane-in-conjunc) of the server chassis and tried to manually attach a hard drive to the backplane without a caddy while the machine was on. (I don't have enough caddies to fill the slots.) When I was fiddling around with it to try to get it into the slot, I must have accidentally shorted something on the backplane with the drive, because the machine immediately shut off and the status LED turned solid amber. On the next reboot (and all subsequent reboots), it gives the error beep code: 1-5-4-2, which indicates a power fault.

Relevant sections from the manual:

p. 63 of the PDF (under BMC feature support):

> #### 4.1.2. Non-IPMI Features
>
> - ...
> - Power fault analysis
>     Power unit management: Support for power unit sensor. The Integrated Baseboard Management Controller (Integrated BMC) handles power-good dropout conditions.

p. 111 of the PDF:

> #### 6.4.6. System Status LED
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Color  State     System Status  Description
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Amber  Solid on  Fatal          Fatal alarm &mdash; system has failed or shut down;
>                                 ...
>                                 Integrated BMC detected
>                                 ...
>                                 4. No power good &mdash; power fault.
> ```

p. 173 of the PDF:

> #### Table 91. Integrated BMC Beep Codes
>
> ```
> Code     Reason for Beep                          Associated Sensors               Supported
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 1-5-4-2  Power fault: DC power unexpectedly lost  Power unit - power unit failure  Yes
>          (power good dropout)                     offset
> ```

From a quick search online, I'm understanding that ["power good"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_good_signal) is a signal alerting that the power supply is working fine, and that "power good dropout" means that this signal is missing. For basic troubleshooting, I've tried switching the power supply twice (once to the other redundant 750W PSU that came with the chassis (which was disconnected when it was shorted)), and to a different generic 775W PSU I had laying around that I know is good. The beep code still happens. On top of that, I tried disconnecting all of the other peripherals to the main motherboard (the other system boards via the bridge board), but the same happens, so I know it's something on the main motherboard (the S5520UR).

I can't get to POST, so not sure if I can do any additional diagnosis or fix anything software-wise.

What are some other possible candidates for causes of this power fault error, if the PSU is (very likely) still good? Is it likely that the motherboard is no good now and I'll have to replace it completely? What is the best mode of diagnosis? There are no visual marks to indicate any breakage besides the status LED. It would be great if I didn't have to order a new one.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be better-received here or at Server Fault -- I moved my other question over to Server Fault b/c it involves a few server-chassis parts, to with which this question deals a lesser degree. I'm not too familiar with either site, so let me know if you think it should be migrated.

Comment: If you did short something, it may have caused overcurrent damage to something on the board. Look closely for damage, perhaps with a magnifying glass. It may not be visible though.